# Learning angular - State and stateparams

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to see how the stuff works with state and stateparams. Came accross a plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/bsq7P9nDL46c3FwXsmBN?p=preview) and started modifying it . In the code below  - $state.href(myStateName, myParams)} does not seem to work . Can anyone explain

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp" ng-strict-di>

  <head>
    <title>my app</title>
    <style>ul { padding-left: 0; } li { list-style: none; }</style>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" 
            src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="'+ document.location.pathname +'" />')
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head> 

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/home">home</a>
      <li><a ui-sref="parent">parent</a>
      <li><a ui-sref="parent.child">child</a>
    </ul>
    
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <input ng-model="myStateName" /><br />
      <input ng-model="myParams.param" /><br />
      <a ng-href="{{$state.href(myStateName, myParams)}}"
       >{{$state.href(myStateName, myParams)}}</a>
    </div>
    
    <div ui-view=""></div>
    
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html"> 
 <div ui-view>
  <h3>current state name: <var>{{$state.current.name}}</var></h3>

  <h5>params</h5>
  <pre>{{$stateParams | json}}</pre>
  <h5>state</h5>
  <pre>{{$state.current | json}}</pre>
  
 </div>
</script>

  </body> 

</html>
```

Comment: where's the accompanying JS code?

Comment: Can you be more specific. What values of state name didn't work for you? Also mention what changes you made.

Comment: I provided a link to the plunker. The JS code is there. Did not want to copy that. In the JS code , for the controller , i changed -  $scope.myStateName = "child"; and the href link in the view disappeared.